# Sudivision modifier distorts mesh

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface, rigify

I had a 3D artist do the weight painting on my mesh so that I can use it with a Rigify rig in Blender. The rig works perfectly and the weight painting did the job, however, after receiving the character back, I noticed that the subdivision modifier is distorting the mesh, to the point where the results are better with the modifier off.

[image]

What could cause this effect?

Link to the .blend object: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8ujnkd10qakzyn/fugaku%20new.blend?dl=0

Comment: Hello, could you please share your object, or at least a part of it? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure. Here is the link to the dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8ujnkd10qakzyn/fugaku%20new.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem with your topology, as you see you must have subdivided with a simple right click > *Subdivide* operation, which has cut the faces by half, but without rounding the shapes. It's already bad as it will tend to make the faces look flat, but they will even look flatter if you add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, because the additional edges will act like support edges that make the angles look sharper, therefore your problem:

[image]

If you select all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide* it seems to work fine without creating too many triangles. Now if you activate the *Subdivision Surface* modifier (btw, put it below the *Armature* modifier) here is what you get:

[image]

If you want to add topology to round objects, don't right click > *Subdivide*, even with the *Smoothness* at 1, instead apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier (but here you don't need to apply a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, the topology seems high enough).

Comment: You are awesome! This has solved my problem. Thank you so much :)